# Problem with custom dialog show in jetpack compose. Not correct background

Tags: background, customdialog

I'm created custom dialog from common class in ini

```
init {
    activity.setContent {
        CustomDialog(viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomDialog(viewModel: ViewModel){
Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = {  },
        properties = DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = true, dismissOnClickOutside = true)
    ) {
}
}
```

But under dialog background is an empty activity, but must be a preference activity.

Not correct composable:
[image: composable]

correct dialog via XML:

[image: xml]

I tried, but didn't help

````
                        Surface(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Transparent)) {
                            CustomDialog(viewModel)
                        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Exampe:

```
Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDismissRequest() }, properties = DialogProperties()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .background(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp)
                ).clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp))
        ) {
    //.....

   }
}
```

Comment: I fink its not a problem of composable view, its something with activity.setContent. Its create as new empty background with navigation bar on the top, but must be last activity with run this composable with no navigation  bar

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
dialog?.window?.setDimAmount(0.0f)
```